# C# ASP.NET web form - how to implement apilayer (currencylayer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, currency, converters

How can I implement live currency prices from https://currencylayer.com/ in an ASP.NET web forms application? It says that you have to type this code (http://apilayer.net/api/live) in the application but I don't know where exactly (.aspx or .aspx.cs ?).

Comment: Look this https://github.com/apilayer/currencylayer-API/blob/master/docs/language-examples/jquery-ajax.md

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.